# Sum of individual elements in a vector

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to determine the sum for each individual element in a vector.

For example, suppose I have the vector

```
x <- c(2,3,2,2,5,5,3,3)
```

and I want to find the sum for each element.

The answer would be something like

```
2: 6
3: 9
5: 10
```

This is because there are three 2's (2+2+2 or 2*), etc.

In other words, I want to essentially multiply the number times the number of times that element is found in the vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using base R `tapply`

```
tapply(x, x, sum)
# 2  3  5 
# 6  9 10
```

If you need it as dataframe wrap it in `stack`

```
stack(tapply(x, x, sum))

#  values ind
#1      6   2
#2      9   3
#3     10   5
```

If you convert this to a dataframe then this becomes ([How to sum a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group))

```
library(dplyr)
tibble::tibble(x) %>%
   group_by(x) %>%
   summarise(n = sum(x))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
#      x     n
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     2     6
#2     3     9
#3     5    10
```

Answer (score 2):

A method with `dplyr`:

```
x <- c(2,3,2,2,5,5,3,3)

a = tibble(x)

a %>% count(x) %>% mutate(xn = x*n)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
      x     n    xn
  <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1     2     3     6
2     3     3     9
3     5     2    10
```

Answer (score 2):

Lots of ways to do this.  A couple of base approaches:

```
with(rle(sort(x)), data.frame(val = values, freq = lengths, prod = lengths*values))

  val freq prod
1   2    3    6
2   3    3    9
3   5    2   10
```

Or:

```
transform(as.data.frame(table(x), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), sum = as.numeric(x) * Freq)

  x Freq sum
1 2    3   6
2 3    3   9
3 5    2  10
```

Comment: You need `prod = as.numeric(as.character(x)) * Freq)` OR `stringsAsFactors = F` in `as.data.frame()` in your second method. Nice answers.

Comment: @Shree - That was sloppy, thanks.  But I think better to avoid having them as factors in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- c(2,3,2,2,5,5,3,3)
tibble(x) %>% 
count(x) %>% 
mutate(xn = x*n ) %>% 
pull(xn)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowsum` from `base R`

```
rowsum(x, group = x)
#    [,1]
#2    6
#3    9
#5   10
```

Or with `by`

```
by(x, x, FUN = sum)
```

Or with `split`

```
sapply(split(x, x), sum)
#  2  3  5 
#  6  9 10
```

Or another option with `xtabs`

```
xtabs(x1 ~ x, cbind(x1 = x, x))
#  2  3  5 
#  6  9 10
```

Or with `ave`

```
unique(data.frame(x, Sum = ave(x, x, FUN = sum)))
#   x Sum
#1 2   6
#2 3   9
#5 5  10
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
data.table(grp = x, x=x)[, .(Sum = sum(x)), grp]
#   grp Sum
#1:   2   6
#2:   3   9
#3:   5  10
```